# Why am I getting "ECHO is OFF/ON"?

Tags: batch-file

Simple question: why is `ECHO is OFF/ON` being printed in a `.txt` file instead of the users' input? I tried various solutions - none of them worked. Any and all help will be appreciated.

### Code

```
@echo off

:start
del "test.txt"
cls
set /p test_test = "> "
echo %test_test% >> test.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
    set file = %%a
)
echo %file%
pause
```

Comment: Remove the spaces in your `SET` commands.

Comment: @Squashman Why would that change anything? I did so - nothing.

Comment: The space is part of the variable name.  If you have a space to the left of the equals sign in a set statement the space becomes part of the variable name.

Comment: @Squashman That isn't changing anything. Pitty. Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: PEBKAC. If you don't believe me open up a cmd prompt and paste this cmd into the cmd prompt: `set test1 =test&set test1=test&set test`

Comment: Just one question what's your aim in this batch file ?

Comment: @Hackoo, totally agree with you on that question. The code is extremely inefficient.  So I too am wondering what the intended goal is.

Comment: @Squashman What the heck are you talking about? I want to believe you but the code you're telling me to use isn't working. I tried it. Here, take [a look](http://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-840269297.gif "Example").

Comment: If even Squashman's correction (changing `set file = %%a` to `set file=%%a`) does not change anything, than `test.txt` must be empty, or it contains empty lines or such beginning with `;`) only...

Comment: @introvertedsouls, I looked at your fancy GIF and you still did not CLOSE UP ALL THE SPACES in your SET commands!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Squashman That was not the case but thanks anyways.

Comment: @introvertedsouls, ummm, yes it was.  Look at the code compo posted and go back and look at your fancy gif you deleted already.  You never closed up the spaces in `set file = %%a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **ECHO** command with no parameters outputs the status of ECHO, which in this case you've set to **off**. Because your **%test_test**% variable is empty, *(due to you setting a variable named **%test_test %**)*, the ECHO command is being entered with no parameters.

```
@echo off

:start
cls
set /p "test_test= > "
(echo %test_test%)>test.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
    set "file=%%a"
)
echo %file%
pause
```

As you may have noted you werre also setting a variable named **%file %** too.

Comment: It's strange that I didn't need to go through all of this when I was creating batch files a couple of months ago and they work perfectly as of now too. Thanks.

Comment: I guess it is just better to post the answer with the code changes then try to help them figure it out.  I think I will just go your route from now on and post the code. I have always believed if you give them the fish they will keep asking for a fish instead of learning to fish.  I guess it is less headaches if you just give them the fish.

Comment: @introvertedsouls. I highly doubt you had spaces before the equals sign in your set statements and it worked in the past.  If you look at HELP documentation for the SET command the second line of the documentation shows the syntax for the command. `SET [variable=[string]]`. Do you see an spaces?

Comment: TBF @Squash I only posted the example because your comments appeared to not be making the same point to the OP as it was to you and I.

Comment: @Compo, It was probably for the best in this situation.